# Cant create item in table as its saying user must exist

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication

Im trying to create an item within a table that i generated using a scaffold in ruby on rails. whenever i try to create the item i got a message saying user must exist. these are my models. Measurment model:

```
class Measurment < ApplicationRecord
    belongs_to :user
end
```

My User Model:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord
  # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
  # :confirmable, :lockable, :timeoutable, :trackable and :omniauthable
  devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
         :recoverable, :rememberable, :validatable

         has_many :measurments
end
```

I have created a database migration which adds the user ID to measurements

```
class AddUserIdToMeasurment < ActiveRecord::Migration[6.1]
  def change
    add_column :measurments, :user_id, :integer
  end
end
```

As this was happening i looked into it and tried to find a fix. Something I came across was to add before_action :authenticate_user! at the top of the controller and i also added  @measurement.user = current_user withing the create method seen below

```
    @measurement = Measurement.new(measurement_params)
    @measurement.user = current_user

    respond_to do |format|
      if @measurement.save
        format.html { redirect_to @measurement, notice: 'Measurement was successfully created.' }
        format.json { render :show, status: :created, location: @measurement }
      else
        format.html { render :new }
        format.json { render json: @measurement.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
```

Now I am getting undefined method `user=' for nil:NilClass. I seen that i need  assossiation between the user and the measurment so you cannot create child without the parent! but as im logged in it user not already created? Any help would be much appreciated

Comment: Check your spelling. You have a mix of `measurement` which is the correct spelling and `measurment`. And you might want to check that `current_user` is not nil.

Comment: Did you try restarting your server?

Answer (score 1):

just some thoughts:

1. make sure your database migration is adding user_id as a reference column (make sure your db is linking user_id column to users table)
2. make sure when you create the @measurements variable you are passing user_id as part of measurement_params into Measurement.new

Maybe put a byebug in there after Measurement.new so you can inspect the @measurements var?